# Trying to get current location, but LocationManager delegate never get called

Tags: ios, delegates, location, mapkit, cllocationmanager

here is my code, i am trying to get my current longtitude and latitude,
so my location will be display on map view.
however, the location manager delegate never get called, so i always getting longitude = 0.0000   and latitude = 0.0000.....

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(retain,nonatomic)CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(assign,nonatomic)float longitude;
@property(assign,nonatomic)float latitude;

@end
```

and this is the implementation file:

```
  #import "MapViewController.h"
    #define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

    @interface MapViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation MapViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }




      - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        [self getCurrentLocation];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
        zoomLocation.latitude = self.latitude;
        zoomLocation.longitude = self.longitude;

        MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

        [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

        NSLog(@"longitu

de %f", self.longitude);
    NSLog(@"latitude %f", self.latitude);


}

    -(void)getCurrentLocation
    {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        [self setMapView:nil];
        [super viewDidUnload];
    }




    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to get your location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
    {
        NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", [locations lastObject]);
        CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
        if (currentLocation != nil) {
            self.longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
            self.latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
            NSLog(@"cal longitude %f", self.longitude);
            NSLog(@"cal latitude %f", self.latitude);
        }
    }
    @end
```

can anyone give me some advise please. cheers

Comment: The calling of delegate method might take sometime.. I doubt you will get the values before your viewWillAppear gets called. Doesn't it ever gets called?

Comment: If delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateLocations` isn't called at all, then make sure you're running the app on iOS 6, and the app is authorized to use location services.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are running the code on simulator and SDK is below 6.0. In this case you get only 0.0000 as latitude and longitude. And make sure that application is granted access to device location.

If you just want to get current location then do the following :

```
-(void)getCurrentLocation
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation currentLocation = self.locationManager.location;
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

BTW, never use `self` when initialize any object. Because doing this creates 2 object.

first object is created by right side of this line `self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];`. Second object is created when setter method is called by left side of the same line, to assign an object to `locationManager` variable.